# Oracle - Query for large dataset taking very long time - Is there a way to optimize it?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Suppose I had a very large table in my Oracle DB filled with data for thousands of items. This data would get updated very frequently throughout the day and each update gets a timestamp.

So, for example, the table looks as follows (I know column names are bad, this is only illustration):

**TBLDaily:**

```
Date:         ItemNo:     CharA:  ....  CharN:    Time_Stamp:
2014/02/15    123         ....                    2014/02/15 10:00AM
2014/02/15    123         ....                    2014/02/15 11:00AM
2014/02/15    123         ....                    2014/02/15 02:13PM
2014/02/15    234         ....                    2014/02/20 01:00PM
2014/02/15    234         ....                    2014/02/20 09:00PM
   ...
2014/02/16    123         ....                    2014/02/20 08:15PM
   ...
```

Then, I have a table with the same item numbers that stores other information, but it stays static throughout the month, so it would look as follows:

**TBLMonthly:**

```
Date:          ItemNo:    CharA:   .... CharK:
2014/01/31     123        ....          
2014/01/31     234        ....          
2013/12/31     123        ....          
2013/12/31     234        ....          
  ...
```

Now, I need to get, for each part number & for each date, the latest information available from the Daily table and, for some characteristics, if they don't exist there, then grab them from the monthly table.

My SQL query looks as follows:

```
WITH All_Data AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Date, A.ItemNo ORDER BY A.Time_Stamp) AS RN,
    A.Date, A.ItemNo, 
    NVL(A.CharA, B.CharA),
    B.CharB,
    ... whatever other characteristics ...

  FROM 
    TBLDaily A,
    TBLMonthly B,

  WHERE
    A.ItemNo = B.ItemNo
  AND
    A.Date BETWEEN To_Date('2012-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND To_Date('2014-02-24', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
  AND
    B.Date = (SELECT max(Date) FROM TBLMonthly WHERE Date <= A.Date)
)

SELECT * 
FROM All_Data 
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Date, ItemNo
```

Now, this query is taking an **immensely** long time to complete (I left it running since yesterday afternoon and it was still executing the query this morning). It is for an extremely large dataset, I know, but I've queried out larger datasets substantially faster. I'm **guessing** that it is due to the either the:

1. `PARTITION BY` 
   or
2. The continual `B.Date = (SELECT max(Date) FROM TBLMonthly WHERE Date <= A.Date)`

But I'm not sure and, even worse, I don't know how to fix it to make it more efficient and not take so long.

Any thoughts / help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You didn't mention it but do you have indexes on these tables? If yes then what indexes and on which columns?

Comment: In addition to what Ziouas asked, did you run an explain plan on the SQL?  Did you get trace data and use TKPROF?  Have your tables been analyzed recently?

Comment: Oh yes, if you could post actual execution plan in txt or xml it would be much appreciated but I believe it's not possible. But maybe you could post estimated?

Comment: PARTITION by DATE,ITEMNO doesn't make sense (2 dates seconds apart for same itemno would both have RN=1).  Try: PARTITION by ITEMNO.  Also, your predicate filter: and b.date = (select max(date)...) is probably causing issues

Comment: There are several tools that provide metrics at the operation level and remove the need to guess which part of the query is slow.  For example: 1) `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */`, 
2) `alter session set statistics_level=all;` 3) SQL Monitoring.  If you frequently deal with long-running SQL statements it's worth the time to understand those tools so you don't have to guess anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your query is easier and quicker with this approach:

```
with t AS
(SELECT DISTINCT LAST_VALUE(CharA) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, ItemNo ORDER BY Time_Stamp) as CharA,
   MAX(Time_Stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, ItemNo) as Time_Stamp
FROM TBLDaily)
SELECT *
FROM t
   JOIN TBLMonthly m ON m.ItemNo = d.ItemNo and t.Time_Stamp = m.Time_Stamp
```

Comment: This is interesting, so a different way to get the single row... Would I need the `LAST_VALUE(CharA) OVER ...` part of the first select?? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: `SELECT LAST_VALUE()` is just a different way for `SELECT ... WHERE x = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM ...)`. In many cases it should be faster than having a Sub-query in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a virtual column on daily table. Should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Is_latest(V_item IN NUMBER, V_MONTH IN DATE, V_time_stamp IN DATE) RETURN DATE IS
    last_ts DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(time_stamp)
    INTO last_ts
    FROM TBLDaily
    WHERE ItemNo = V_item
        AND DATE = V_MONTH;
    IF last_ts = V_time_stamp THEN
        RETURN trunc(last_ts, 'mm')
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;

ALTER TABLE TBLDaily ADD month_of_TS GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Is_latest(ItemNo, Date, time_stamp));

CREATE INDEX IND_XXX on TBLDaily (ItemNo, month_of_TS);

Select *
from TBLDaily d
   JOIN TBLMonthly m ON m.ItemNo = d.ItemNo and m.Date = d.month_of_TS
```

Comment: Wow! - I have to admit, I don't understand this, but trying to wrap my head around it now... Thanks for the new bits of logic to look at!!